# Animate object size within GameScenes.swift (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

We need to animate an object's size within GameScene.swift. Other Stack Overflow posts suggest using `UIView.animateWithDuration`, but this isn't available inside GameScene.swift. We need to animate inside GameScene.swift because we also need access to SKAction to run an action forever.

Right now, we are using the code below, but it is too clunky. The hope is animation will smooth out the appearance of the object as it shrinks.

```
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(shrinkItem),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
            ])
        ))

func shrinkItem() {
    let curWidth = item.size.width
    if curWidth < 15 {
        return
    }
    item.size = CGSize( width: CGFloat(item.size.width - 20 ), height: CGFloat(bird.size.height - 20) )
}
```

Comment: What is GameScene.swift? Did you try importing UIKit?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to shrink your bird, right ? That correspond to scale it down.

Why are you doing it manually inside a `runBlock` ?

You might want to give a look at the *SKAction Class Reference* : http://goo.gl/ycPYcF.
Inside which you'll see all the possible actions, and `scaleBy:duration:` (or another one) might be what you're looking for.

```
let shrinkAction   = SKAction.scaleBy(0.5, duration: 1.0)
let waitAction     = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([shrinkAction, waitAction])
let repeatAction   = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)

self.yourBirdNode.runAction(repeatAction)
```

*Depending on what you'll do next, take note that some action are automatically reversible (through `reversedAction`) and some aren't.*